# Failed cardano-node build on mac m1

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I've followed the installing-cardano-node#macos guide on the developer portal and about 10 things fail to build and all of them are giving me the same error.

```
Cannot specify -O# and --passes=/--foo-pass, use -passes='default<O#>,other-pass'
`opt' failed in phase `LLVM Optimiser'. (Exit code: 1)
```

I also followed the steps on this link and I'm still getting the same errors.

https://github.com/mallapurbharat/cardano-tx-sample/blob/main/0_installation/preview_preprod_network/1_macos_m1_process.md

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with LLVM version 15, as per https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21936

Looks like reverting to LLVM 14 should work for you.

Comment: Reverted to LLVM 13 and it worked! (I was getting some other errors on LLVM 14)

Comment: Nice one, glad it worked ok.